# How to save graph / image from CGI website in python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KMDW/2014/11/17/MonthlyHistory.html?req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA

On the link above, I am trying to save the "Monthly Weather History Graph" in a python script. I have tried everything I can think of using BeautifulSoup and urrlib.

What I have been able to do is get to the point below, which I can extract, but I can not figure out how to save that graph as an image/HTML/PDF/anything. I am really not familiar with CGI, so any guidance here is much appreciated.

```
div id="history-graph-image"

img src="/cgi-bin/histGraphAll?day=17&year=2014&month=11&ID=KMDW&type=1&width=614**" alt="Monthly Weather History Graph" /
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the page with `requests`, parse the HTML with `BeautifulSoup`, find the `img` tag inside `div` with `id="history-graph-image"` and get the `src` attribute value:

```
from urlparse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url = 'http://www.wunderground.com'
url = 'http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KMDW/2014/11/17/MonthlyHistory.html?req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
image_relative_url = soup.find('div', id='history-graph-image').img.get('src')
image_url = urljoin(base_url, image_relative_url)
print image_url
```

Prints:

```
http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/histGraphAll?day=17&year=2014&month=11&ID=KMDW&type=1&width=614
```

Then, download the file with [`urllib.urlretrieve()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve):

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(image_url, "image.gif")
```